# Propel 1.6, Phing, Windows 7 - How to set this up?

Tags: php, propel, phing

I am trying to get the "propel-gen reverse" command working, but just can't seem to get the setup right.

Right out of the box, I get this error:

```
... generator/bin/propel-gen: line 69: phing: command not found
```

I downloaded phing 2.4.5 and added the bin folder to my PATH, but that just brings more errors (build.xml not found, default.tasks not found...etc). Too many various errors to list, really.

Bascially what I am asking is this: has anyone successfully gotten the "propel-gen" command to work properly using XAMPP on a Windows machine? If so, how?

NOTE: I have looked at [this site](http://preenet.com/blog/?p=34), but there seems to be several missing pieces as it also results in all the errors I experience above. My guess is it isn't compatible with XAMPP.

Thanks!

Comment: did you restart your shell or your computer after modifying `PATH`? If not, do so. Also check PHP's include path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be on the right track. The error comes from the generator command, and is as a result of "phing" not being recognised as a command from that environment. Make sure you quit and restart your console after resetting the env vars in the My Computer dialogue box - often I found path stuff won't percolate through unless you do this.

Incidentally I developed using Propel 1.2/1.3 on XP with an ordinary WAMP manual install for several years - worked a treat. Live was Windows as well, though we finally moved to Linux, and it did run better :)

Comment: No worries. You may find my [blog post](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/02/some-pointers-on-propel-1-5/) on getting started with Propel of interest. I did that all on a Mac, but there's no reason why it shouldn't work on Windows.